# How to emulate statically the C bitfields in c#?

Tags: c#, bit-fields

I have to define a communication protocol and I want to use a bitfield to store some logic values.

I'm working on the both systems: the sender: a device and a .Net software as receiver.

On the firmware side, I defined as usually a bitfield struct like:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) BitsField 
{
  // Logic values
  uint8_t vesselPresenceSw: 1;
  uint8_t drawerPresenceSw: 1;
  uint8_t pumpState: 1;
  uint8_t waterValveState: 1;
  uint8_t steamValveState: 1;
  uint8_t motorDriverState: 1;
    // Unused
  uint8_t unused_0: 1;
  uint8_t unused_1: 1;
};
```

How I can define a same structure on the software side that support a bytes deserialization to build the struct itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I had a similar idea @Dmitry.
I found the following solution using `FieldOffset` attribute.
Working well without additional code. I think it's acceptable.

```
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LiveDataBitField
{
    // Where the values are effectively stored
    public byte WholeField { get; private set; }

    public bool VesselPresenceSw
    {
        get => (WholeField & 0x1) > 0;
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                WholeField |= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                WholeField &= 0xfE;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool DrawerPresenceSw
    {
        get => (WholeField & 0x2) >> 1 > 0;
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                WholeField |= (1 << 1);
            }
            else
            {
                WholeField &= 0xFD;
            }
        }
    }
    public bool PumpState
    {
        get => (WholeField & 0x4) >> 2 > 0;
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                WholeField |= (1 << 2);
            }
            else
            {
                WholeField &= 0xFB;
            }
        }
    }
    public bool WaterValveState
    {
        get => (WholeField & 0x8) >> 3 > 0;
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                WholeField |= (1 << 3);
            }
            else
            {
                WholeField &= 0xF7;
            }
        }
    }
    public bool SteamValveState
    {
        get => (WholeField & 0x10) >> 4 > 0;
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                WholeField |= (1 << 4);
            }
            else
            {
                WholeField &= 0xEF;
            }
        }
    }
    public bool MotorDriverState
    {
        get => (WholeField & 0x20) >> 5 > 0;
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                WholeField |= (1 << 5);
            }
            else
            {
                WholeField &= 0xDF;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To deserialize a byte array to struct you can use:

```
    public static object ReadStruct(byte[] data, Type type)
    {
        var pinnedPacket = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var obj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(pinnedPacket.AddrOfPinnedObject(), type); 
        pinnedPacket.Free();
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: You're placing all your fields at the same offset.  That's effectively the same as using a single field, so why not just use a single field?  Also, your `set` logic is wrong.  Try setting one to `true`, then back to `false` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeStrobel, I fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there is no direct C# equivalent to C-style bitfield structs.

C# is capable, to a limited extent, of approximating C-style *unions* by using `FieldOffset` attributes.  These explicit layout attributes allow you to specify exact and potentially overlapping field offsets.  Unfortunately, that doesn't even get you halfway there: the offsets must be specified in *bytes* rather than bits, and you cannot enforce a specific width when reading or writing overlapping fields.

The closest C# comes to natively supporting bitfields is probably flag-based `enum` types.  You may find this sufficient, provided you don't need more than 64 bits.  Start by declaring an `enum` based on the smallest unsigned type that will fit all your flags:

```
[Flags]
public enum BitFields : byte {
    None             =      0,
    VesselPresenceSw = 1 << 0,
    DrawerPresenceSw = 1 << 1,
    PumpState        = 1 << 2,
    WaterValveState  = 1 << 3,
    SteamValveState  = 1 << 4,
    MotorDriverState = 1 << 5
}
```

The named items can have any value assigned to them that fits within the underlying type (`byte` in this case), so one item could represent multiple bits if you wanted it to.  Note that if you want to interop directly with a C-style bitfield, your first value should start at the *most significant* bit rather than the least.

To use your flags, just declare a variable or field of your new type and perform whatever bitwise operations you need:

```
BitFields bits = BitFields.None;

bits |= BitFields.VesselPresenceSw | BitFields.PumpState;
bits &= ~BitFields.VesselPresenceSw;

// etc.
```

On the upside, enums declared with `[Flags]` are nicely formatted when displayed in the debugger or converted to strings.  For example, if you were to print the expression `BitFields.VesselPresenceSw | BitFields.PumpState`, you would get the text `DrawerPresenceSw, PumpState`.

There is a caveat: the storage for an `enum` will accept any value that fits within the underlying type.  It would be perfectly legal to write:

```
BitFields badBits = (BitFields)0xFF;
```

This sets all 8 bits of the `byte`-sized enumeration, but our named values only cover 6 bits.  Depending on your requirements, you may want to declare a constant that encompasses only the 'legal' flags, which you could `&` against.

If you need anything richer than that, there is a framework-level 'bitfield' data structure called [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx).  However, `BitArray` is a reference type that uses a managed `int[]` for storage.  It's not going to help you if want a `struct` that you could use for interop purposes or any kind of memory mapping.

Comment: Just wanted to comment about possibility of using [Flags] enum and you're updating your answer :) I think it's the best and the simplest way to solve this problem

Comment: @pkuderov  Agreed!  I'm a bit embarrassed it took me so long to think of it :).

Answer (score 1):

Please see an example,

C code,

```
struct example_bit_field
{
unsigned char bit1 : 1;
unsigned char bit2 : 1;
unsigned char two_bits : 2;
unsigned char four_bits : 4;
}
```

and C# equivalent,

```
[BitFieldNumberOfBitsAttribute(8)]
struct ExampleBitField : IBitField
{
[BitFieldInfo(0, 1)]
public bool Bit1 { get; set; }
[BitFieldInfo(1, 1)]
public byte Bit2 { get; set; }
[BitFieldInfo(2, 2)]
public byte TwoBits { get; set; }
[BitFieldInfo(4, 4)]
public byte FourBits { get; set; }
}
```

Source :- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095576/Bit-Field-in-Csharp-using-struct

Comment: Yes, but I need to create an attribute! I was wondering that there was a short solution

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can try *mimic* such a `struct`. It seems, that you want to use it in the *interop* (say, `C` routine exchange data with `C#` program). Since you have *logic* values, let expose them as `bool`:

```
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  ...

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  public struct MyBitsField {
    private Byte m_Data; // We actually store Byte

    public MyBitsField(Byte data) {
      m_Data = data;
    }

    private bool GetBit(int index) {
      return (m_Data & (1 << index)) != 0;
    }

    private void SetBit(int index, bool value) {
      byte v = (byte)(1 << index);

      if (value)
        m_Data |= v;
      else
        m_Data = (byte) ((m_Data | v) ^ v);
    }

    public bool vesselPresenceSw {
      get { return GetBit(0); }
      set { SetBit(0, value); }
    }

    ...

    public bool motorDriverState {
      get { return GetBit(5); }
      set { SetBit(5, value); }
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
  var itemToSend = new MyBitsField() {
    vesselPresenceSw = false,
    motorDriverState = true,
  };
```